# what (?:*) mean in javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/(?:(?:^|.*;)\s*key\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/
```

I got this RegExp which can get the key in cookie ,but I don't know what

`(?:^|.*)` mean , I mean what `?:` mean in javascript

Comment: RegExp explained: https://regex101.com/r/uU0gM2/1

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. `(?:^|.*)` matches either the beginning of a line/string or any number of characters but a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` would define a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). `(?:)` will make it [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group).

[Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, I would disagree. When a question is *what is x*, the answer *it's like y, but with this difference* should be more than satisfactory given knowing what *y* is.

Comment: *"given knowing what y is"* - If someone doesn't know the difference between the syntax it's quite possible they wont know the terms either. There's little reason to not include explanations of those terms.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, read OP's question. He is comfortable with ordinary brackets, he is just confused about the `?:` part.

Comment: OP is but others may not be when searching this question.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, I'm sure others that search for *what is `?:`?* wouldn't want to see explanation of things like `()`. If they want to learn that, they would search for `()` instead, or even better, they should take 15 mins to read about regex basics.

Comment: @ndn please check if my edit is ok. If not, undo!

Comment: @Jonny5, I appreciate your change. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is called `Non-Capturing Groups: (?: … )`

For instance `(?:Mofei|Zhu)` matches `Mofei` or `Zhu`—but the name is not captured.